# Filter rows in dataframe based on string value in column

Tags: r

I have the following:

```
Engine      HorsePower      Type
Model 1        500          V10
Model 2        230          A7
Model 3        330          IVTEC
Model 4        400          V8
Model 5        300          VX500
```

I want to filter the rows in the dataframe above, where the column for "Type" begins with the letter "V"

Hence I would get:

```
Engine      HorsePower      Type
Model 1        500          V10 
Model 4        400          V8
Model 5        300          VX500
```

The data type of each column above is of type "factor". I attempted something like:

```
new_df <- new_df$AVC == "V"
```

But the resulting output is just FALSE and TRUE. Would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_df[grepl("^V", new_df$Type),]
```

This will give you all the rows where `new_df$Type` starts with a `"V"`.